# Trying to use a numericupdown not in a void

Tags: c#

I am trying to make an integer = numericupdown not within a method. What I am trying to say is I want to initialize an integer that can be used every where in the main form.

```
int number1 = Convert.ToInt32(numericUpDown1.Value);
```

I want to define it before I call any events so I can use it everywhere. Thanks

Comment: Add it as a field on the form.

Answer (score 0):

Create a static class and set your property number1 to a static property.

```
public static class KeySets
{
    public static int Number1 { get; set; }
}
```

then set property

```
KeySets.Number1 = Convert.ToInt32(numericUpDown1.Value);
```

then you can use it every where.

Answer (score 0):

I see at least 2 options:

1: declare it as a field and initialize in constructor after InitializeCompoenent()

```
int number1;
public MyForm()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    number1 = Convert.ToInt32(numericUpDown1.Value);
}
```

2: Create a property returning what you want

```
int number1
{ 
    get { return Convert.ToInt32(numericUpDown1.Value); }
}
```